# Aparece null no lugar do nome recuperado

Tags: java, android, null, sharedpreferences

Ao ver a aplicação, vejo que na variável `nomedoHumano` aparece `null`, e era para aparecer o nome do usuário.

Logo abaixo do método `Onclick`, recupero o nome digitado. Já pensei em botar para recuperar acima da `String`, mas não dá certo.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textoNovaFrase;
    private Button botaoNovaFrase;
    private Preferencias preferencias;
    private String nomedoHumano;

    private String[] frases = {
            nomedoHumano + "se você traçar metas absurdamente altas e falhar, seu fracasso será muito melhor que o sucesso de todos",
            "O sucesso normalmente vem para quem está ocupado demais para procurar por ele",
            "Se você não está disposto a arriscar, esteja disposto a uma vida comum"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textoNovaFrase = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textoNovaFraseId);
        botaoNovaFrase = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoNovaFraseId);

        botaoNovaFrase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Preferencias preferencias = new Preferencias(Conversa.this);
                nomedoHumano = preferencias.getNomeDoHumano();

                Random randomico = new Random();
                int numeroAleatorio = randomico.nextInt( frases.length );

                textoNovaFrase.setText( frases[ numeroAleatorio ] );
            }
        });

    }
```

Abaixo o codigo do meu `SharedPreferences`:

```
public class Preferencias {
    private Context contexto;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private final String NOME_ARQUIVO = "ssistente.preferencias";
    private final int MODE = 0;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    //Dados assistente
    private final String CHAVE_NOMEASS = "nomeDoAssistente";
    private final String CHAVE_SEXOMASASS = "seoxMasDoAssistente";
    private final String CHAVE_SEXOFEMASS = "seoxFemDoAssistente";

    //Dados Humano
    private final String CHAVE_NOMEHUM = "nomeDoHumano";
    private final String CHAVE_SEXOMASHUM = "sexoMasDoHumano";
    private final String CHAVE_SEXOFEMHUM = "sexoFemDoHumano";

    private final String CHAVE_SEXOHUM = "sexoEscolhidoHum";
    private final String CHAVE_SEXOASS = "sexoEscolhidoAss";

    // Como foi seu dia?
    private final String CHAVE_DIA = "respostaEscolhida";




    public Preferencias( Context contextoParametro){

        contexto = contextoParametro;
        preferences = contexto.getSharedPreferences(NOME_ARQUIVO, MODE );
        editor = preferences.edit();

    }

    public void salvarDadosNomeeSexo( String nomeDoAssistente, String sexoMasdoAssistente, String sexoFemDoAssistente,
                             String nomeDoHumano, String sexoMasdoHumano, String sexoFemDoHumano,
                             String sexoEscolhidoAss, String sexoEscolhidoHum){

        editor.putString(CHAVE_NOMEASS, nomeDoAssistente);
        editor.putString(CHAVE_SEXOMASASS, sexoMasdoAssistente);
        editor.putString(CHAVE_SEXOFEMASS, sexoFemDoAssistente);
        editor.putString(CHAVE_NOMEHUM, nomeDoHumano);
        editor.putString(CHAVE_SEXOMASHUM, sexoMasdoHumano);
        editor.putString(CHAVE_SEXOFEMHUM, sexoFemDoHumano);
        editor.putString(CHAVE_SEXOASS, sexoEscolhidoAss);
        editor.putString(CHAVE_SEXOHUM, sexoEscolhidoHum);
        editor.commit();



    }


    public void salvarDadosDia(String respostaEscolhida){
        editor.putString(CHAVE_DIA, respostaEscolhida);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getDadosAssHum(){

        HashMap<String, String> dadosAssHum = new HashMap<>();

        dadosAssHum.put(CHAVE_NOMEASS, preferences.getString(CHAVE_NOMEASS, null));
        dadosAssHum.put(CHAVE_SEXOMASASS, preferences.getString(CHAVE_SEXOMASASS, null));
        dadosAssHum.put(CHAVE_SEXOFEMASS, preferences.getString(CHAVE_SEXOFEMASS, null));

        dadosAssHum.put(CHAVE_NOMEHUM, preferences.getString(CHAVE_NOMEHUM, null));
        dadosAssHum.put(CHAVE_SEXOMASASS, preferences.getString(CHAVE_SEXOMASHUM, null));
        dadosAssHum.put(CHAVE_SEXOFEMASS, preferences.getString(CHAVE_SEXOFEMHUM, null));

        dadosAssHum.put(CHAVE_SEXOASS, preferences.getString(CHAVE_SEXOASS, null));
        dadosAssHum.put(CHAVE_SEXOHUM, preferences.getString(CHAVE_SEXOHUM, null));

        return dadosAssHum;
    }

    public String getNomeDoAssistente(){
        return preferences.getString(CHAVE_NOMEASS, null);
    }

    public String getNomeDoHumano(){
        return preferences.getString(CHAVE_NOMEHUM, null);
    }


    public String getRespostaEscolhida(){
        return preferences.getString(CHAVE_DIA, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Você obtém `nomedoHumano` através de  `preferencias.getNomeDoHumano()`, adicione à pergunta o código da classe Preferencias.

Answer (score 0):

Aparece "null" porque, quando o array `frases` é construído, o campo `nomedoHumano` é `null`.

O que o array guarda na posição `0` é o resultado da expressão

```
nomedoHumano + "se você traçar metas absurdamente altas e falhar, seu fracasso será muito melhor que o sucesso de todos"
```

que é a concatenação do valor do campo `nomedoHumano`, naquela altura, com o expressão entre aspas.

Qualquer alteração posterior do valor do campo não alterará o valor guardado no array.

Comment: e existe alguma forma de eu fazer aparecer o nome?

Comment: Sempre que obter/alterar o valor de `nomedoHumano` reconstrua a posição `0` do array: `frases[0] = nomedoHumano + " se você traçar metas absurdamente altas e falhar, seu fracasso será muito melhor que o sucesso de todos";`